# Stop iTerm2 from using disk (disk cannot be ejected)

Tags: terminal, external-disk, iterm, eject

How can stop iTerm2 from using the mounted disk I `cd`'d into? Sometimes, even when i `cd` out, it's still blocking the disk. I have to ⌘-Q the entire program which is very irritating. It's just idling anyway, there is no point in blocking the disk. So how can I disable it? I'm surprised I couldn't find any Google results either.

Force unmounting the disk does the trick for the time being: `diskutil unmount force /Volumes/MyVolume`, however, I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: The culprit here is not iTerm2 but OS X itself. Every process has assigned an open file/directory `cwd` (it can be inspected in the shell using `lsof -p $$ | grep cwd`). Since every process inherently uses a CWD, I see only 2 ways to resolve this: 1) Apple changes this behaviour (very unlikely), or 2) ask Bash mailing list to resolve this issue by occupying eg `/tmp` when idling, and only changing directory to the actual CWD when spawning processes. (maybe not that unlikely)

Comment: I'm guessing the fact that `cd`ing out doesn't work sometimes is due to spawned background processes/workers.

Comment: Just contacted bug mailing list. I proposed implementing this behind a `shopt -s cwdspoof` option

Comment: After you cded in what commands have you run before cding out?

Comment: @Mark not sure, I couldn't reproduce it since I had figured that that's probably the cause.

Comment: You just have to kill the tabs that had previously cd'ed into the disk. I don't know of any other workaround.